# Getting a minimal working example using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am just trying to get a minimal working example with Biblatex so that I can learn how to use the package. I am using TexMaker, and keep getting the same warning, together with a warning that my citation "dirac" is undefined:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
```

In my preamble I have the following:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

In my document I have:

```
I am citing Dirac \cite{dirac}
```

In the file sample.bib, which is saved in the same folder as the main .tex file, I have:

```
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}
```

This was mostly copied directly from the Overleaf help pages.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: nothing wrong, you always get that warning the first run. as it says, run biber to generate the bibliography, then re-run pdflatex to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do as @DavidCarlisle has already suggested you do in a comment, i.e., run biber after a preliminary LaTeX run, followed by another LaTeX run, you'll end up with something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International Series of Monographs on Physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
I am citing Dirac \cite{dirac}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```